# Keep Point(2) or Vector2(2) joined to Point(1) or Vector2(1)

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

Imagine a segmented creature such as a centipede.  With control of the head segment, the body segments are attached to the previous body segment by a point.

As the head moves (in the 8 cardinal/inter-cardinal directions for now) a point moves in relation to its rotation.

```
public static Vector2 RotatePoint(Vector2 pointToRotate, Vector2 centerOfRotation, float angleOfRotation)
{
    Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angleOfRotation);
    return Vector2.Transform(pointToRotate - centerOfRotation, rotationMatrix);
}
```

Was going to post a diagram here but you know...

```
 center(2)      point(2)                      center(1)    point(1)



                                                     point(1)                    

                point(2)    ^                                        |
                           / \                                       |
                            |                                        |
 center(2)                                           center(1)      \ /
                                                                     V
```

I have thought of using a rectangle property/field for the base sprite,

```
private Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(-16, 16, 32, 32);
```

and checking that a predefined point within the body segment remains within the head sprite's bounds.
Though I am currently doing:

```
     private static void handleInput(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Vector2 moveAngle = Vector2.Zero;

        moveAngle += handleKeyboardMovement(Keyboard.GetState()); // basic movement, combined to produce 8 angles
                                                                  // of movement

        if (moveAngle != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            moveAngle.Normalize();
            baseAngle = moveAngle;
        }

        BaseSprite.RotateTo(baseAngle);

        BaseSprite.LeftAnchor = RotatePoint(BaseSprite.LeftAnchor,
 BaseSprite.RelativeCenter, BaseSprite.Rotation); // call RotatePoint method

        BaseSprite.LeftRect = new Rectangle((int)BaseSprite.LeftAnchor.X - 1,
 (int)BaseSprite.LeftAnchor.Y - 1, 2, 2); 
 // All segments use a field/property that is a point which is suppose to rotate around the center
        // point of the sprite (left point is (-16,0) right is (16,0) initially
        // I then create a rectangle derived from that point to make use of the .Intersets method of the
        // Rectangle class

        BodySegmentOne.RightRect = BaseSprite.LeftRect; // make sure segments are connected?

        BaseSprite.Velocity = moveAngle * wormSpeed;

        //BodySegmentOne.RightAnchor = BaseSprite.LeftAnchor;

        if (BodySegmentOne.RightRect.Intersects(BaseSprite.LeftRect)) // as long as there two rects occupy the 
        {                                                             // same space move segment with head

            BodySegmentOne.Velocity = BaseSprite.Velocity;
        }

    }
```

As it stands now, the segment moves with head but in a parallel fashion.  I would like to get a more nuanced movement of the segment as it is being dragged by the head.

I understand that the coding of such movement will be much more involved than what I have here.  Some hints or directions as to how I should look at this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to implement this yourself or are you ok with using a physics engine like Farseer (http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com)? The reason I ask is that what you want to do is not trivial and involves knowledge of physics engine concepts.

Comment: The nominal solution would be to write my own solution; however, if using an established system will accelerate my ability to  come up with a solution I'm all for it and will look further into Farseer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will describe what you need to do using a physics engine like Farseer but the same holds if you want to write your own physics engine.

1. Create a Body for each articulated point of the centipede body.
2. Create a Shape that encapsulates the outer shell that will be attached to each point.
3. Attach the Body and Shape using a Fixture. This creates one link in your centipede.
4. Attach multiple links using a SliderJoint.

For example - assuming that the outer shell of each link is a circle, here's how to create two links and join them together.

```
    Fixture fix1 = FixtureFactory.CreateCircle(_world, 0.5f, 1, new Vector2(-5, 5));
    fix1.Body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;

    Fixture fix2 = FixtureFactory.CreateCircle(_world, 0.5f, 1, new Vector2(5, 5));
    fix2.Body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;

    JointFactory.CreateSliderJoint(_world, fix1.Body, fix2.Body, Vector2.Zero, Vector2.Zero, 10, 15);
```

Now applying a force on any of the bodies or collisions on the shapes will drag the second joint around - just like you want.

This is all just stick physics - so you could implement your own if you REALLY wanted to. ;)